# Lodash deep pick

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, lodash

Hi I'm getting data from a soap service and transforming the xml to json and getting the value I need like this:

```
console.log(result['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['ns2:getFichaGeneralResponse']['return']['instituciones']['datosPrincipales']['registros'][1].valor)
```

is there any way to do something like this?

```
console.log(_.pick(result, 'registros'))
```

So I can get an object with the information I need?

Comment: How looks `result` variable? What is its structure? This console.log throws an error `console.log(result['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['ns2:getFichaGeneralResponse']['return']['instituciones']['datosPrincipales']['registros'][1].valor)`

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you have a complicated object and you want to pick some props by the specified path?

For example, you want to get `{ d: 'foo', e: 'bar' }` by path `a.b.c` from the object below:

```js
var object = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: 'foo',
        e: 'bar',
        f: 'baz'
      }
    }
  },
  g: {
    h: 1
  }
};

function pickPropsByPath(object, path, arrayOfPropsNames) {
  return _.pick(_.get(object, path), arrayOfPropsNames);
}

console.log(pickPropsByPath(object, 'a.b.c', ['d', 'e'])) // => { d: 'foo', e: 'bar' }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```